# Как правильно запустить PHP?

Tags: php

Из учебника PHP взял пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Заголовок страницы</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "hdr">
            <p>Ваш заголовок</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form action="php/test.php" method="get">
            <p>HDD:</p>
            <input type="text" name="HDD" />
            <br />
            <p>CD-ROM:</p>
            <input type="text" name="CD-ROM" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
            </form>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p class = "footerstyle">Текст внизу<p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Затем из того же учебника взял следующий текст

```
<?php
   echo "<p>HDD is " . $_GET['HDD'] . "</p>"; 
   echo "<p>CDROM is " . $_GET['CDROM'] . "</p>"; 
?>
```

и вставил его в файл php/test.php. Но когда я открываю свою страницу в HTML-редакторе, ввожу значения полей, и нажимаю отправить, открывается файл test.php как простой текст. Как сделать так, чтобы он открывался как исполнимый файл?

PS. Источник примера: https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP, я заменил в нем localhost, поскольку пока не разобрался, как его настраивать, но это уже тема другого вопроса.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Для локальной разработки вам необходимо сначала поднять собственный сервер. Сделать это возможно различными способами, самый простой, как написал @ArchDemon - использовать встроенный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачайте OpenServer по данной ссылке https://ospanel.io/ Установите там всё описано, когда создадите виртуальный диск в папку domain скопируйте папку со своим проектом, запустите OpenServer,откройте проект PHP должен заработать.
Вот пошаговое описание установки OpenServer:
https://www.ipipe.ru/info/ustanovka-openserver.html.
Также можно использовать Denwer, но он по моему субъективному мнению менее удобен.
Данные сервера являются локальными(находятся на Вашем ПК).
Если буду вопросы пишите в комментарии помогу!

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Идёт скачивание, пишет 3 часа. После установки приложения что нужно будет делать?

Comment: https://www.ipipe.ru/info/ustanovka-openserver.html Здесь всё написано)

Comment: Запустите его, а потом на новом виртуальном диске в папку domain добавьте папку со своим проектом. Нажмите на флажок мои сайты и выберите свой и запускайте)

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Всё получилось)

Comment: @ПавелСумароков удачи Вам)

Answer (score 2):

Исполняются только скрипты, это файлы у которых расширения .php и выполнять их должен сервер, он может быть локальный или удаленный, по факту сервер это комп с установленными программами такими как ngix или apache или еще что то эти программы принимают http запросы и отдают ответы а вот ответы могут генерироваться на php.
Вам нужно поставить себе на пк веб сервер например open server или денвер, затем создать там в директории сайта скрипт например index.php и в нес написать обработку вашей html формы и саму форму тоже можно вывести. Почитать можно про это [тут](https://siteclinic.ru/blog/technical-aspects/open-server/)